Can you assign a backup heir in a will in case one heir pre-deceases the testator?
Alice is writing a will, and wants to leave her assets to her two children Bob and Carla, with each receiving a 50% share. By my understanding, if Bob pre-deceases Alice, Carla will get everything. However, in that event, Alice wants Bob's share to go to his son Dan. Is it possible to structure the will to allow this?
Alice could always adjust her will at any time, but let's assume that she is anticipating not being mentally competent to do so.
(not sure if this belongs here or on the law stackexchange; mods please move it if necessary)

I’m voting to close this question because it is not about personal finance. Consider asking it at Law@SE.

I agree with littleadv that this question belongs on law.SE and not here, but more importantly, Alice needs to be advised to consult a lawyer and not rely on advice from random strangers on law.SE while drafting her will.

The single word answer is yes.

In the USA, this is state specific, so when you go to law.se be sure to say where Alice will die. If Alice dies in Texas, for example, no matter where her will was signed, if Bob has a child and pre-deceases Alice, the child inherits Bob's share no matter what the will says. This is codified in Texas law as their "anti-lapse statute" and knowing obscure details like this is why we pay attorneys to get things right.

Look into the difference between 'per stirpes' and 'per capita', invented for just this situation.

[law.se] may be able to pvide a general answer, but they'll also advise Alice to have the will written by a competent estate attorney, who can make sure all the i's and t's are dotted and crossed.

I’m voting to close this question because this question is about wills and that is out of scope for Money SE.

Yes, absolutely you can. In fact it's done very often.
It's extremely normal that for a married couple, if there is a surviving spouse everything goes to them. And if there isn't then it goes to other people as specified.
You can write a wide variety of things in a will, and conditions for if someone is already dead is a common one.
